# Youtube-DL Error web page

Tags: ubuntu, youtube, youtube-dl

Why when use Youtube-dl on linux ubuntu server many link generate this output?

```
[youtube] Setting language 
[youtube] Lj1wqKh8dxI: Downloading video webpage ERROR: unable to download video
                       webpage: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [video in question](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lj1wqKh8dxI) is blocked from  many locations. You (or more precisely, the [geolocation of your IP address](http://www.maxmind.com/app/locate_my_ip)) have to be in the US to watch the video.

Comment: You can't fake your IP address, since the packets youtube sends will be returned to it, and youtube blocks the video. I don't know exactly, but there may be some other locations within Europe or around the world where the video works. It all depends on the local copyright laws and youtube's implementation thereof.

Comment: I do not understand, youtube-dl used with the video from my PC works perfectly. But if I use it on a server located in germany does not work, this means that in germany this video is not viewable?

Comment: Precisely. The exact error message from Germany is: `Unfortunately, this video is not available in Germany because it may contain music for which GEMA has not granted the respective music rights.`. For background, refer to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesellschaft_f%C3%BCr_musikalische_Auff%C3%BChrungs-_und_mechanische_Vervielf%C3%A4ltigungsrechte).

Comment: thank you very much, now I see, so the problem is the server, or better than where the server is located